# Access output in Ubuntu 14.04 terminal that has 'disappeared' off the terminal window

Tags: linux, terminal, output, ubuntu-14.04

I just ran a script on a server that generates a lot of output on the command window.

However, now, after running it for roughly 4 hours I want to check all the output, but the beginning of the output has already disappeared from the terminal window. When I scroll up, it is not there anymore.

Is there any way to access this? It needs to be via commands in the terminal because I'm running it on a server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to redirect the output to a file & open the file to check for all the output.

You can also redirect the script by running it in background & saving the output to a file. Do let me know what type of command you are running for which I can give you the exact command. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah that would be great, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm running a python script on it. Is that what you need to know? Let me know if you need some other specifics.

Comment: nohup python filename.py > output.txt 2>&1&
where filename would be your script name.
output.txt would be the output file.

If this doesn't work try using the following:-
python filename.py > output.txt

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work, the second one. What exactly does '2>&1&' do? Also, is there a way to write it both to the screen and to the file?

Comment: 2>&1& is used for logs. As i wasn't aware of your script to I recommended it. It outputs the Standard Error (2) to Standard Output (1) and last & means to run in background.

Yes you can do that, using python filename.py | tee output.txt
If you want to append in output.txt file everytime you run you can use the following:-

python filename.py | tee -a output.txt

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It outputs neither to the terminal, nor to the file. My command now is:
python SGD_mnist_fully_connected.py --output-prefix output | tee output.txt.  

'--output-prefix outpout' is a variable that is necessary for the script to run.

Comment: I tried using a sample file & it's showing me perfectly.

Trying running this:- python SGD_mnist_fully_connected.py --output-prefix output | tee output.log

Also seeing a . after txt is it by mistake????
python SGD_mnist_fully_connected.py --output-prefix output | tee output.txt

Comment: Same story unfortunately when I try log. Weird, I have no idea what's going wrong then. Oh no the full stop was just to end the sentence, I didn't actually used that in my command.

Comment: Post the error what you are seeing or something on which I can analyze & try to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

if it's a real terminal and not a virtual terminal
you need to recompile your kernel and increase the buffer size of your terminal.

in the .config file of your kernel the parameter you need to increase is 
`CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK_SIZE`

Comment: Ok thanks, would that still save my current output? Or would that only help in the future? Also, how to get to the file?

Comment: This will not save the output of your current session. it will only apply to future sessions. if you wish to compile the kernel you must download the sources and refer to some manual explaining how to configure the kernel. you must do that carefully as you may harm your system.

Comment: Ok, it is probably a bit too technical solution for me then.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, redirecting I/O interferes with many programs (for instance, changing the output from a [`tty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tty.1.html) to a plain file).  Use the [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) program to capture *all* output from programs run in a shell, with *minimal* interference.